# generate java code from wsdl in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using [wsdl2code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/home.aspx) web tool for generating Java code for given wsdl.
But , generated code has the different definition of the method from web-service.
Method in wsdl contains the return type boolen but in wsdl2code generated code contains the same method with void return type.

I tried to create the client using axis2 plugin but that code is not working for android , many APIs are not resolved like rmi ..

What is the best way to generate java code from wsdl in android.

I have already spent lot of time and didn’t get any good solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ksoap2`, you can generate java classes via online web tool [EasyWSDL](http://easywsdl.com/).

Comment: yes I tried easywsdl too but, that I am getting "method is available only fro premium user"

Comment: Really? I've done with easywsdl to generate java classes from wsdl about 3 months ago, it was free. Just login via Google/Facebook or sighup then generate.

Comment: yes but unfortunately its not free for one of that method